# Download multiple excel files from database in Python

Tags: python, database, excel, download

I want to download all the excel files of 202 countries from this website:

1. Go to this link:
   http://investmentpolicyhub.unctad.org/IIA/IiasByCountry#iiaInnerMenu

2.Click each country name in the table, for example:

Angola is here:
http://investmentpolicyhub.unctad.org/IIA/CountryBits/5#iiaInnerMenu

3. Then, click 'Export' to download the file

Could you please help me how to do this in Python?

The link to each country actually only changes in the number (5 for example for Angola)

However, I do not know how to write the code to click to the excel box and download in Python :(

Could anyone help me with this?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the request package to download the file (right click the button to see the link)

```
import requests

url =('http://investmentpolicyhub.unctad.org/Download/ExportCountryBits/5?'
       'sortColumn=InvolvedPartiesName&sortOrder=1')
res = requests.get(url)
res.raise_for_status()

# write the file to your current folder
with open('myfile.xlsx', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(res.content)
```

Comment: Hello Meow, Thank youvery much for the help. It works beautifully.